# Place Your Bets - in sequence, of course

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence

> #### Your Puzzle

There is some sort of pattern in cards below. Simply figure out what the next card should be.

[image: What is next>]

Note: You cannot re-use a card already in play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that

> Every line of three cards that pass through the Jack of Hearts in the center tallies to 21. Therefore the missing card is an Ace.

Note that

> One of the cross rows has 2 hearts and a club...so maybe this diagonal does too?

So then

> The missing card is the Ace (of Hearts?)